# I can't get my background to scale itself down in Pygame, what do I do?

Tags: python, pygame, scaling, pygame-surface

Take a look at "pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (-500, 600))" below, set it up just like it told me on Pygame's site, so don't know what else to do

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption('Climbing Man')

bg_image = pygame.image.load("/Users/apple/Downloads/Python Projects/Climbing_Game/bckwall.jpg").convert
pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (-500, 600)) 


def climbing_man():
    pass

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.blit(bg_image,(-50,0))
         

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) returns a new *Surface* with the scaled size. Therefore you have to assign the return value  `bg_image`:

<s>`pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (-500, 600))`</s>

```py
bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (500, 600))
```

However, you cannot scale to a negative size. If you want to flip an image you have to use [`pygame.transform.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip):

```py
bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (500, 600))
bg_image = pygame.transform.flip(bg_image, True, False)
```

---

In addition, you forgot the parentheses after `convert`:

<s>`bg_image = pygame.image.load("/Users/apple/Downloads/Python Projects/Climbing_Game/bckwall.jpg").convert`</s>

```py
bg_image = pygame.image.load(
    "/Users/apple/Downloads/Python Projects/Climbing_Game/bckwall.jpg").convert()
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption('Climbing Man')

bg_image = pygame.image.load(
    "/Users/apple/Downloads/Python Projects/Climbing_Game/bckwall.jpg").convert()

bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (500, 600))
# bg_image = pygame.transform.flip(bg_image, True, False) # <--- OPTIONAL


def climbing_man():
    pass

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.blit(bg_image,(-50,0))
         

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I've done exactly as you said and this is what I got                                                           
File "/Users/apple/Downloads/Python Projects/Climbing_Game.py", line 9, in <module>
    bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg_image, (50, 60)) 
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method

Comment: @Hussein You missed the parentheses after `convert`: `.convert` -> `.convert()`

Comment: thanks a bunch man, it works!!!! It's always those small things that get me :(